# Writing a loop in a shell script to read output of HIVE Select

Tags: sql, shell, hive, hiveql

I am new to writing shell scripts.  I currently have some reports that we run in HIVE SQL and I am trying to automate them the best I can.  Currently I use crontab within our UNIX environment to have these queries run automatically everyday.   Right now I have to paste that data into excel then filter and create separate documents for each "end-user".

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

I have a column in my output query that shows the name of a company, CompanyA, CompanyB, CompanyC
etc.  Depending on the details in there it could be anywhere from 12-20 different "companies".  I don't want to hard code a query for each one to create it's own output.  What I would like to do, is have a query that selects each unique company in that field(agency_name) and then run my select statement that would say:

`select * from output_results where agency_name = "name here"` and then write this output to a csv named Balance_Detail_"NAME"_Date then loop through and run this query and create an output for each name it found in the agency_name field.

Comment: Sorry we can't write the code for you. What you're asking sounds very possible. I would first create a query that just generated of Company names that you'll be processing on this run of your script, saving those values as plainly as possible to a file. Then you can wrap your `select` statment above in a loop, `while read co_name ; do printf "select .... $co_name ....\n" | sqlClient ...args... | awk '...post filtering...' > $co_name.txt < co_nameFileList.txt` Would be the general outline, but will require a fair amout of work on your part to get it to work and then bullet-proof it for errors.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I apologize if it seemed like I was looking to have it written for me.  I was more just trying to understand if the thoughts I had in my head were possible and how to even start that process.  Thank you for your suggestion.  I will start looking into that and see how I get along.

Comment: Very good! Best to post a new Q or anything that is slowing  you up, trying to keep it focused on one problem at a time. Best if you can include small sample set of data, required output from that sample, current output, code, and exact text of error messages. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to get `code/data/output/errMsg` formatting. Try to make it so it is copy/pasteable by readers. Also recall that we won't have access to your databases, but include which client you are using from cmdline (no GUIs!). `sqlplus` or `isql` are common. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a template how you can loop query result and call another hive script and to save in a CSV. Needs debugging. And of course use your queries:

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')

for NAME in $(hive -S -e "select distinct agency_name from ..... ") 
 do 
  #echo "Company name is $NAME"
  hive -S -e " select * from output_results where agency_name = $NAME" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > Balance_Detail_${NAME}_${dt}
 done
```